# Planning our drop-box to sharepoint migration, is it user-based or site-based

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, content-migration, document-migration

I have performed many SharePoint on-premises to SharePoint online migrations. but i have a project to do a migration from drop-box to sharepoint online. now i read about drop-box and seems it is a personal cloud storage, where users upload and share files. so when i want to plan a drop-box to SharePoint migration, is this done on user-basis ? for example we need to migrate each drop-box storage to the user's one-drive or to a separate site? or inside drop-box we can access all the files and folders for all users from a single place, so we can migrate them to a single site at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what plan of Dropbox you are using in your organization, *Dropbox Basic* or *Dropbox Business*.

For example, Microsoft has introduced a new tool called **Mover** that supports migration from Dropbox. It provides both *Dropbox (Single User) Connector* and *Drobox Business (Admin) [Connector](https://mover.io/connectors/)*.

If you are an administrator for Dropbox Business, you can authorize or add a Multi-User Dropbox Business account as a connector. 
(See the tutorial [here](https://mover.io/guides/migrating-dropbox-to-office-365/#setting-up-the-migration).)

Reference:

[Migrating your content to SharePoint and OneDrive.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/migrate-to-sharepoint-online)

---

**UPDATE:** 
There are four kinds of destination you can select from.

[image]

If you choose to authorize *Office 365*, then Mover will scan all the available destination (sites) in this tenant. 
You can select one or multiple sites from the list and do the migration at one time.

Different user can be migrated to the same destination folder/site, or you can manually edit the destination folder so that they can be in different folders of the same document library.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply. but in-case of Dropbox basic, then how the tool will migrate the users' Dropbox-es, will it create a main folder for each user? or we need to migrate each user's Dropbox into a separate SharePoint site?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev I’ve added more info to the answer. Please see the update.

Comment: so drop-box business is mainly similar to OneDrive personal site? where users upload personal files and share some/all of them with other users? so when we plan to migrate drop-box to SharePoint, we are mainly talking about a drop-box site per user?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev Correct, Dropbox is similar to OneDrive. You can give the tool a try. Both Dropbox Basic and Mover are free to use.